# Transaction Stream parameter and method not recognized

Tags: java-sdk, event-stream

I'm trying to set up a transaction listening stream. I have taken the Java snippet directly from the [docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html). Below is the part that is giving me an issue.

```
Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
final KeyPair account = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GC2BKLYOOYPDEFJKLKY6FNNRQMGFLVHJKQRGNSSRRGSMPGF32LHCQVGF");

PaymentsRequestBuilder paymentsRequest = server.payments().forAccount(account);

paymentsRequest.stream(new EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) { ... }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the `OperationResponse` as the type parameter in the `EventListener`, specifically stating:

Type `java.util.EventListener` does not have type parameters

Also, the `@Override` is not overriding a method from its superclass and `onEvent` is never used.

I can't think what I am missing as this is taken straight from the docs and I know that the Stellar SDK is correctly setup in my app as I am already performing successful transactions.

FYI, this code snippet is sitting within the following method:

```
public void StellarTransactionListner(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your import statements. You may have the wrong `EventListener` in scope.  The [SDK's EventListener](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/requests/EventListener.java) is type parameterised and declares the method `void onEvent(T object)`.

Comment: Simple but effective! Thank you. It turns out I had `import java.util.*` as an import statement, which was 'blocking' the import prompt on the `EventListener `.